# How to design regex pattern to match string

Tags: python, regex

```
import re
text = "**Company** [Click1](call:58200) ******provides*** **housekeeping** **clean***"
bold = re.findall(r'\*{2}(\w+?)\*{2}', text)
print bold
```

> **result:** ['Company', 'provides', 'housekeeping', 'clean'] 
>   
> **expect:** ['**Company**', '**housekeeping**']

How do I design regex pattern to grep it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with [**Lookaround**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

> The lookaround actually matches characters, but then gives up the match, returning only the result: match or no match

```
(?<!\*)\*{2}\w+?\*{2}(?!\*)
```

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/oI2vJ8/1)

Sample code:

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'(?<!\*)\*{2}\w+?\*{2}(?!\*)')
test_str = u"**Company** [Click1](call:58200) ******provides*** **housekeeping** **clean***"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

Pattern explanation:

```
  (?<!                     look behind to see if there is not: 
    \*                       '*'
  )                        end of look-behind

   \*{2}                    '*' (2 times)
  \w+?                     word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or more times)
   \*{2}                    '*' (2 times)

   (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
     \*                       '*'
   )                        end of look-ahead
```

Comment: oh guy this working fine.<br>
and your regex tool that's interesting. : )
**Thank You.**